# A question from Dummit-Foote on showing nontrivial algebraic extensions of a certain field (Section 14.9, Q.15)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to solve a problem from Dummit-Foote's Section 14.9 (problem 15):

> Let $K_0= \mathbb Q$ and for $n > 0$ define the field $K_{n+1}$ as the
> extension of $K_n$ obtained by adjoining to $K_n$ all roots of all
> cubic polynomials over $K_n$. Let $K$ be the union of the subfields
> $K_n$. Prove that there are nontrivial algebraic extensions of $K$.

I have tried a lot but can't figure out how to show this. I'm guessing that attaching roots of some irreducible quartic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ might give a contradiction, but I am stuck. Can someone please provide some hints?

Comment: Actually, irreducible quartics will *not* yield a contradiction. This is because every subgroup of $S_4$ has a composition series whose factors are $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (extension by a quadratic polynomial) and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (extension by some $x^3-a$ if you start from $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/3}$, which is a harmless assumption). Instead, let $L/F$ be generated by taking all the roots of *some* cubic polynomial. What can you say about $[L:F]$? Can you “iterate”?

Comment: Can't we argue that every element of $K$ can be written in terms of element of $\mathbb Q$ using arithmetic and $n$th root operations? Therefore, we should be able to obtain a contradiction by attaching roots of some *quintic* polynomial over $\mathbb Q$? (I suppose another approach is to look at degrees? Perhaps we can say that adjoining a root of a cubic polynomial increases the degree by a factor of $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$. Whereas adjoining a root of an irreducible quintic gives you an extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree $5$.)